# MySQL (MariaDB) backend for Django under Python3 on Debian

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am attempting to configure Django running under Python3 on a Debian box to use MariaDB as its backend. If I alter my `mysite/settpings.py` as per the tutorial i.e.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':     'foo',
        'USER':     'tim',
        'PASSWORD': 'swordfish',
        'HOST':     'localhost'
    }
}
```

I get a lot of grief, culminating in

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    'Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?' % e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'.
Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
```

Now, obviously, MySQLdb doesn't work on Python3 and although I have installed the mysql connector package doesn't seem to work.

If I try using the connector [recommended](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html) by MySQL

i.e.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME':     'foo',
        'USER':     'tim',
        'PASSWORD': 'swordfish',
        'HOST':     'localhost'
```

then I get a load of grief culminating in

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name 'BaseDatabaseFeatures'
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Further to Matt Seymour's suggestion if I attempt a pip (actually pip3 as my system Python is still 2.x) install of `mysqlclient` I get the following...

```
tim@merlin:~/mysite$ sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9uub69zo/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9uub69zo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9uub69zo/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9uub69zo/mysqlclient
```

Could the fact that I am using MariaDB rather than MySQL be significant here?

Comment: how did you install the python-mysql package? I would strongly recommend using virtualenv over any system packages. Activate your env then `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some messing around I have an answer of sorts, although not as satisfactory as I would like.

The `MySQLdb` library isn't supported under Python 3.x, and so you should use the `mysqlclient` fork of it instead. However, because I am using the MariaDB fork of MySQL, some of Debian's dependencies required to install `mysqlclient` are unmet. I don't want to revert to MySQL as I am using MariaDB for other purposes.

So, as all I needed was a fairly robust, multi-user back-end RDBMS, I've installed PostgreSQL for use with Django which seems to work nicely enough.